# Wordpress "too many redirects" without typing index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my Wordpress installation.

Problem:
If I enter http://www.mydomain.de then an error is thrown "too many redirects".
If I enter http://www.mydomain.de/index.php, the page will display correctly.
If I have a simple index. php (Text) in the directory, not Wordpress. If this is displayed normally on http://www.mydomain.de

Configuration:
Web server (Debian) with a VM (Debian).
On the VM is the Wordpress installation. The web server forwards to the VM.
PHP mod_rewrite is enabled.

Configuration Apache Webserver:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin     webmaster@localhost
    ServerAlias     www.mydomain.de
    ProxyPass        / http://192.168.56.112/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.56.112/
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration Apache VM:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        Servername www.mydomain.de

        DirectoryIndex index.php
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Configuration. htaccess VM:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Do you have any idea where I got the mistake?

Comment: The index.php is available in the directory.

Comment: yeah, I see it can be really misleading.
This means, without the entry of index.php in the address line.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a different story :-)

Comment: Virthualhost and htaccess are OK, 100%. the problem seems related to proxy settings.

Comment: One more question: can you add screenshot from your Wp-Admin General Settings page? There are two important fields there: site URL and home URL - thay also can cause similar problems if to write there incorrect data.